# Python activate windows with the same name

Tags: python, window, hwnd

So what I need do to is periodically change the active window, my issue is that they all have the same name and using their HWND only works for the first window. Besides that i'd like to not have to insert it's HWND everytime

```
import win32gui, time

def main():
    while(1):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(788574)#win2
        side()
        time.sleep(5)

def side():
    while(1):
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(3147934)#win1
        main()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When you say same name, you mean same text in title bar?

Comment: Exactly, they both have the same text, i've tried using their HWND but still won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through selected windows, there's a few steps:

- Use **win32gui.EnumWindows** to go through all open windows
- Use **win32gui.GetWindowText** to get the title bar text from a window
- Use **win32com.client.Dispatch** and **SendKeys** to activate the switch process
- Use **win32gui.SetForegroundWindow** to select the window to activate

Here's the code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import win32gui
import time

title = "Untitled - Notepad2"  # cycle all windows with this title

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
    
top_windows = []  # all open windows
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)

winlst = []  # windows to cycle through
for i in top_windows:  # all open windows
   if i[1] == title:
      winlst.append(i)
      
for x in range(5):  # cycle 5 times
   for w in winlst:  # each window with selected title
       shell = win32.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")  # set focus on desktop
       shell.SendKeys('%')  # Alt key
       win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(w[0]) # bring to front, activate
       time.sleep(2)  # 2 seconds
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Using the code you gave as an example I've been able to do it, thanks for your help!